# new level warning from removed term in formula

Tags: r, formula

What is going on here? My formula excludes a column but cv.glm complains about missing levels.

```
> glm.fit = glm(
+   relprice ~ .-unit,
+   data = glmset
+ )
> cv.glm(glmset, glm.fit, K = 10)
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev =         object$xlevels) : 
  factor unit has new levels
```

Am I losing my mind? Current workaround is to exclude the column, but that's going to get old.

Comment: Please give us your `glmset` to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ha, I was just finding that `boot::cv.glm` produces quite a lot of unintelligible errors. This one may make sense with the context of the dataset, though.

Comment: it could be your cross validation set has levels that do not exist in your training set.

Comment: This is actually how glm / lm works: if a variable is included in the data statement, and in the formula, it will throw errors if a factor has only one level. Wee example, `mtcars$new <- factor(c(rep(1, 31), 2))` . This throws an error: `m = glm(mpg ~ . - new, data=mtcars[1:31, ]) `as new has only one level in the dataset and is used in the formula. So one way you can omit the variable in the data argument : `m = glm(mpg ~ . , data=subset(mtcars[1:31, ], select=-new)`) - which i guess is what you are doing - or type the variables that you want to include explicitely.

Comment: I'm using:
`glmset[,names(glmset) != "unit" ]`
or
`glmset[,!names(glmset) %in% c("unit") ]`
is subset superior?

Comment: @user3513243 ; definitely not. I would use the second of your choices in the comment above (although id tweak the brackets `glmset[,!(names(glmset) %in% "unit") ]`) . i used subset for brevity